# How to get factory method to return a derived class?

Tags: c++, factory-method

I am trying to make a factory method, but it is currently throwing an error:

```
core\loaders\loader.cpp:11:12: error: cannot convert 'Jpeg' to 'Loader*' in assignment
   15 |     loader = Jpeg(path);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
      |              |
      |              Jpeg
```

I would like to return a class that is derived from `Loader`, in this case that would be `Jpeg`. As seen in the code below it does extend the `Loader` class, and what I have read is that you can use a pointer to the base class, set it, then return it, so I have tried doing that without success. How can I get my factory to return `Jpeg` (and eventually a `Png` class).

Here is my Loader header and source:

```cpp
// loader.h
class Loader {
public:
  static Loader* get(char* path);
};

// loader.cpp
Loader* Loader::get(char* path) {
  string pathStr(path);
  pathStr = pathStr.substr(pathStr.rfind(".") + 1);

  Loader* loader;
  if (pathStr == "jpeg" || pathStr == "jpg") {
    loader = Jpeg(path);
  }

  return loader;
}
```

The `Jpeg` class then extends the `Loader` class:

```
class Jpeg : public Loader {
protected:
  char* path;

public:

  Jpeg(char* path) {
    this->path = path;
  }
};
```

Comment: `loader` is a pointer, you can't just assign an object to it. You probably meant `loader = new Jpeg(path);`, but you should be using smart pointers instead.

Comment: Try this - `new Jpeg(path)`, in place of `Jpeg(path)`.

Comment: That works! But how come in some cases (other classes) it throws an error when I use the new keyword?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn _But how come in some cases (other classes) it throws an error when I use the new keyword?_ Show your code where you are getting error.

Comment: So for example, in another spot, I had `static RGBColor rgb(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255);` but then I changed it to `static RGBColor* rgb(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255);` (note the `*`) and had to use `RGBColor(...)`, adding the `*` I can now use `new RGBColor(...)`.

Comment: `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: Why you changed the return type of function `rgb()` from `RGBColor` to `RGBColor *`? What was the problem you were facing? May you would like to ask it in another question.

Comment: There wasn't really a problem, I just couldn't use `new` on it and wasn't sure why. The above comments helped me understand why.

Comment: If you type `new` then you need to type `delete` at some point.  It's unrelated to this question, just be sure that you actually need to dynamically allocate, and even more so that you need to use dynamic allocation manually.

Comment: @StephenNewell thanks, I will take a closer look at my code and see what I can do.

Comment: Again, you _really_ should be using [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936) instead of raw `new`/`delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory - type of `loader` is `Loader *` which is pointer to `Loader` type. You can only assign an address to a pointer. `Jpeg(path)` will create an object of type `class Jpeg` and not a pointer of type `class Jpeg`. Looking at your use case, you need to allocate object of type `Jpeg` dynamically:

```
loader = new Jpeg(path);
```

Once you are done with the `Jpeg` object, make sure to dealloate the memory using `delete` operator.

---

`C++` discourages the use of bare pointers, instead, you should prefer to use the [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). A smart pointer is an abstract data type that simulates a pointer while providing added features, such as automatic memory management. In your code, you can use them like this -

```
  std::shared_ptr<Loader> loader;
  if (pathStr == "jpeg" || pathStr == "jpg") {
      loader = std::make_shared<Jpeg>(path);
  }
```

You need to change the return type of `Loader::get()` function as well -

```
  std::shared_ptr<Loader> Loader::get(char* path) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and need to do changes in function declaration as well in the similar way.

Also, when coding in `C++`, avoid using the `char *` type and prefer to use `string` type. For e.g. -

```
    std::string s{"test.jpeg"};
    std::shared_ptr<Loader> x = Loader::get(s);
```

In `Loader::get()`, change the parameter type to `std::string &` (`std::string` reference) :

```
std::shared_ptr<Loader> Loader::get(std::string & path) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Need to do changes in `class Jpeg` also:

```
class Jpeg : public Loader {
protected:
    std::string path;

public:

    Jpeg(std::string & path) {
        this->path = path;
    }
};
```

Comment: `unique_ptr` might be more appropriate here, and that `path` argument should probably be `const`.